# Prolog: How to check if a predicate exists?

Tags: prolog

How can I check if a predicate exists in a Prolog program? That would be an `exists/1`, like:

```
?- exists(some_predicate).
false.

?- assert(some_predicate).
true.

?- exists(some_predicate).
true.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [current_predicate/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=current_predicate/1), [current_predicate/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=current_predicate/2) or [predicate_property/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=predicate_property/2) (for the last you will probably need [functor/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=functor/3)):

```
?- current_predicate(a/1).
false.

?- functor(A,a,1),predicate_property(A,visible).
false.

?- functor(A,a,1),current_predicate(_,A).
false.

?- assert(a(42)).
true.

?- current_predicate(a/1).
true.

?- functor(A,a,1),predicate_property(A,visible).
A = a(_G136).

?- functor(A,a,1),current_predicate(_,A).
A = a(_G122).
```

`current_predicate/2` and  `predicate_property/2` (with visible) succeeds if the predicate can be autoloaded while `currrent_predicate/1` fails

Answer (score 1):

the 'old fashioned way', but accepted in ISO, is [clause](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=clause/2)/2. You could encounter it while reusing/browsing some of the older examples.

example:

```
?- [user].
|: app([], Y, Y).
|: app([X|Xs], Y, [X|Zs]) :- app(Xs, Y, Zs).
|: % user://1 compiled 0,15 sec, 17 clauses
true.

?- clause(app(X,Y,Z),Body).
X = [],
Y = Z,
Body = true ;
X = [_G338|_G339],
Z = [_G338|_G342],
Body = app(_G339, Y, _G342).
```

Comment: This is accepted in ISO only for predicates with the public property! By default it does not work for static code.