# How to get current working directory

Tags: prolog, yap

I'm new with `yap` (and with Prolog in general), and I can't figure out how to get the current directory.

In fact, I can't make sense of the documentation:

> `working_directory(-CurDir,?NextDir)`
>
> Fetch the current directory at `CurDir`. If `NextDir` is bound to an atom, make its value the current working directory.

I don't understand what's meant by "**at** `CurDir`".

Also, I can't find documentation on the `-` and `?` preceding the formal arguments.  (I guess that the `?` means that the argument is optional, but I have no clue about the `-`.)

Bottom line, I can't figure out how to use this information to query for the current working directory.

---

I've tried many blind guesses, and always get either `no.` or an error in response.  E.g.:

```
$ yap
% Restoring file /usr/lib/Yap/startup.yss
YAP 6.2.2 (x86_64-linux): Sat Nov 23 17:51:47 UTC 2013
   ?- working_directory(CurDir).
no
   ?- working_directory(-CurDir).
no
   ?- working_directory().
     SYNTAX ERROR at user, near line 7:
 working_directory(
<==== HERE ====>
 ).
   ?- working_directory.
no
   ?- CurDir.
     ERROR!!
     INSTANTIATION ERROR- meta_call(_131099): expected bound value
   ?- -CurDir.
no
   ?- working_directory('.').
no
   ?- working_directory(-'.').
no
```

---

I have two questions:

1. Where can I find meta-documentation on the `-`, `?`, and `+` that appear in front of formal arguments in the `yap` documentation?
2. How do I get the current working directory?

---

UPDATE: The following also fail:

```
$ yap
% Restoring file /usr/lib/Yap/startup.yss
YAP 6.2.2 (x86_64-linux): Sat Nov 23 17:51:47 UTC 2013
   ?- working_directory(X, '').
no
   ?- working_directory(X, X).
no
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Meta-documentation can be found in the SWI-Prolog manual [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=preddesc), but will be the same for Yap (couldn't find any reference in the Yap manual for notation at a glance).
2. Current working directory (CWD) can be retrieved like so:

`working_directory(X,'').`

... which means unify X with the CWD and change it to nothing (counter-intuitive, I know, but I didn't make it), or:

`working_directory(X,X).`

... as pointed out by @PauloMoura, which means unify X with the CWD and change it to itself (which also seems weird to me, but c'est la vie).

CWD can be changed like so:

```
working_directory(X,'Some New Directory').
```

... which will unify X with the CWD then change the CWD to 'Some New Directory', so X will be the Previous Working Directory.

Comment: To query the current directory without changing it, the usual idiom is `working_directory(X,X)`.

Comment: @PauloMoura Aha - that makes sense, kinda.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the SWI-Prolog docs.  I tried both `working_directory(X, '').` and `working_directory(X, X).`, but they both result in `no.`.  (I've updated my post accordingly.)

Comment: @kjo Are you certain that your installation is a-ok, including all the packages shared with SWI?

Comment: @JimAshworth: I installed `yap` with `apt-get install yap`...  For good measure, I just re-installed `yap` from scratch (`apt-get purge swi-prolog yap; apt-get autoremove --purge; apt-get install yap`); I still get the same results I showed before.  FWIW, when I installed `yap` for the second time just now, `apt-get` did not report installing any additional packages.  How can I troubleshoot my installation further?

Comment: @kjo Getting out of my comfort zone right now (never actually installed Yap, and not near Unix at the moment), but you could try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886179/prolog-how-to-check-if-a-predicate-exists to check that working_directory/2 exists?